# Fancybox link not working with submit button

Tags: jquery, html, fancybox, fancybox-2

Okay, so I have a fancybox, now currently working, but it isn't working entirely properly. It only works in an actual text-link, not when I have it as an  over a submit button. Well, I shouldn't say that it doesn't work, rather it works and the fancybox closes automatically within under a second, or lasts about a second if I'm lucky, but it never stays open (it does stay open from a text link).

The FB code:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
 $("#top-login-button").click(function() {
  $.fancybox({
   padding    : 15,
   href       : "#login_form_ajax",
   afterClose : function(){ // it was onClosed for v1.3.4
    $("#login_error").hide();
   }
  }); // fancybox
 }); //click

 $("#login_form_ajax").bind("submit", function() {
  if ($("#login_name").val().length < 1 || $("#login_pass").val().length < 1) {
   $("#login_error").show();
   $.fancybox.update(); // it was $.fancybox.resize(); for v1.3.4
   return false;
  }
  $.fancybox.showLoading(); // it was $.fancybox.showActivity(); for v1.3.4
  $.ajax({
   padding : 15,
   type    : "POST",
   cache   : false,
   url     : "anyPage.php?page=ajax",
   data    : $(this).serializeArray(),
   success: function(data) {
    $.fancybox(data);
   }
  });
  return false;
 }); // bind
}); // ready
</script>
```

The Fancybox open links:

```
<a id="top-login-button" href="#login_form_ajax" rel="gallery">Open login form</a>
```

The above works. The one below, works and closes automatically.

```
<a id="top-login-button" href="#login_form_ajax" style="text-decoration:none" title="X">  
<input class="czas" type="submit" name="ajax" value="X"></a>
```

Any ideas? I'm at a loss.

Comment: why are you wrapping a `submit` button inside an anchor? (that's odd) ... that may have the `submit` action triggered and refresh your fancybox/page... why don't use `<button id="top-login-button" data-fancybox-href="#login_form_ajax">open form</button>` instead?

Comment: That's how I got it to work with Fancybox 1.3.2, now that I've upgraded to Fancybox 2, it still semi-works, semi since it starts to open and auto closes. Your idea of a button didn't exactly work, and I'm not sure if I had stuck with your button element if it would have worked eventually (I assume so), at any rate, I have managed to fix the problem by using your idea of a button and nixing the anchor, `<input class="czas" id="top-login-button" onClick="#login_form_ajax" type="button" name="ajax" value="X">` It's still a little fitsy, but 9/10 times it works, and when it doesn't, reclick works.

Comment: I ran out of space, so to continue, I am now encountering a new issue, and I don't understand what it is and why I'm getting it (in FireBug, and Google JavaScript Console). FB: SyntaxError: illegal character / #login_form_ajax, GJC: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL. The code works, and as said, runs into the auto close every once in a while but it is manageable now, but cannot figure out the illegal character part. Any idea? (Thanks, by the way, for the button idea)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modified what JFK had stated with what my original code was, end result, which works perfectly:

```
<input class="czas" id="top-login-button" data-fancybox-href="#login_form_ajax" type="button" name="ajax" value="Enter Starting Time">
```

Don't know how to properly thank JFK, since he didn't post an answer to the question...